# Change active status depending on balance and paymentID

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables:

- Table #1: offerID, activeStatus
- Table #2: offerID, paymentID, price

I want to change `activeStatus` if balance of one `paymentID` is more than price. I used this code for one `paymentID`, but I don't understand how use it for multiple `paymentID`s.

Code for nodejs:

```
update table1
set activeStatus = 0
where activeStatus = 1 and
(
    (paymentID = 1 and price > ${balance1}) or
    (paymentID = 2 and price > ${balance2}) or
    (paymentID = 3 and price > ${balance3}) or
    (paymentID = 4 and price > ${balance4}) or
    (paymentID = 5 and price > ${balance5}) or
    (paymentID = 6 and price > ${balance6})
)

update table1
set activeStatus = 1
where activeStatus = 0 and
(
    (paymentID = 1 and price <= ${balance1}) or
    (paymentID = 2 and price <= ${balance2}) or
    (paymentID = 3 and price <= ${balance3}) or
    (paymentID = 4 and price <= ${balance4}) or
    (paymentID = 5 and price <= ${balance5}) or
    (paymentID = 6 and price <= ${balance6})
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's play with numbers.
You have $100 on the balance.
And you have some payments, let's try put all this into the table:

| # | Balance before | Payment | Balance after |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 10 | 90 |
| 2 | 90 | 50 | 40 |
| 3 | 40 | 60 | -20 |
| 4 | -20 | 20 | -40 |

Ok,As you can see, our balance illuminated on the 3-d step.

This is one of the cases.

Try another case, when we have balance in $100 at the begining, and bill from 4 positions for amount 10+50+60+20 = $140.
So, we can deactivate account when we pay all bill.

| # | Balance before | Payment | Balance after |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 10+50+60+20 | -40 |

Answer to your situation depends on what exactly you want - change status after chacking each payment, or process all payments as one bill?

For first case is better to use some loop to interate by payments one-by-one (and ordder of this payments is very important).
In the second case you can just agregate all payments and apply it to the balance amount.